# Views - Display grouped dates per node

Tags: 6, datetime, views

I have a Committee content type which has multiple meeting dates.

I'm trying to get a View that shows multiple Committees and meeting dates.  Basically, like so:

```
Committee A
1/1/2012
2/1/2012

Committee B
1/2/2012
2/2/2012
```

Instead I get:

```
Committee A
1/1/2012

Committee A
2/1/2012

Committee B
1/2/2012

Committee B
12/2/2012
```

I have tried Group Multiple Fields, but the checkbox does not stay checked after I save.  Any pointers much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the Date module.  Found this in the Issues queue:

#### Group Multiple Value functionality is broken, patch for review

in http://drupal.org/node/1086100

The patch in #2 there worked for me.  Hope it gets rolled in, but in the meantime hope this saves someone else some time.